# Best JS framework(Angular/React/Vue) to use in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, development, angularjs, angular2, reactjs

We have tools (Basically CRUD operations in multiple lists across sites/site collections. Handles large amount of data and has lots of business functionalities/logic) that were built using jQuery and Datatables.js. We are planning to rebuild in 2013. Visual Studio/ server side coding is not allowed.

Can anyone suggest which JavaScript framework (Angular Js1.x, Angular 2+, React, Vue/ Others) is best to use in SharePoint 2013?

Difficult to get Node.JS/NPM/CLI on DEV environment. we have tried a PoC in Angular 4 using SystemJs-Manual mapping concept. But not sure how bundling and future upgrade will be if CLI/NPM is not used.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks,
Puli

Answer (score 0):

This is something that developer has to choose the Javascript framework for development in which they are having good knowledge. So, I will summarize this in my point of view.

For CRUD operations and dashboard development in SharePoint 2013, I will use the following frameworks (in the descending order of preference):

1. **AngularJS 1x**: An incredibly robust JavaScript framework for data-heavy sites and I am using this for very long time.
2. **JQuery**: A fast, small, JS object library that streamlines how JavaScript behaves across different browsers.
3. **Plain JavaScript**: JavaScript is client-side scripting. The most widely used client-side script—nearly every site’s front end is a combination of JavaScript and HTML and CSS.

But in the future for SharePoint Online sites, SharePoint farmework will be used for development. So for development using SharePoint framework wide range of javascript frameowrks can be used.

You can use any JavaScript framework that you like: React, Handlebars, Knockout, Angular, and more.
The toolchain is based on common open source client development tools such as npm, TypeScript, Yeoman, webpack, and gulp.

You can refer the following article for more detailed information about SharePoint Framework:
[Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)